# Problem related to prime ideals of B and A where B is integral over A

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $ A $  be an entire ring, integrally closed. Let $ B $ be entire, integral over $A$. Let  $ Q_1, Q_2$ be prime ideals of $B$ with $Q_1 \supseteq Q_2$ but $Q_1 \neq Q_2$. Let  $P_i=Q_i \bigcap A$. Show that $ P_1\neq P_2$.

Please give some hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "**entire** ring"

Comment: entire ring is the integral domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $P_1=P_2$. Then $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are two different prime ideals lying over the same prime ideal $P$ in $A$. By the *incomparability theorem*, see for example Corollary $14.15$ [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf), neither $Q_1\subset Q_2$ nor $Q_2\subset Q_1$, a contradiction. Hence $P_1\neq P_2$.

Comment: where is the link to incomparability theorem?

Comment: It's famous and you can find it in for example **Atiyah, Macdonald**'s book *introduction to commutative algebra*

Comment: thanks!...it is Going down theorem

Answer (score 1):

Can you reduce to the case of $Q_2 = P_2 = 0$? Having done this, take a non-zero element $x$ of $Q_1$ and try to use an equation of integral dependence for $x$ over $A$ to get something in $P_1$. It doesn't seem to me that we need to start off assuming that $A$ and $B$ are integral domains.